# does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, redux-toolkit

Im new to typescript, here i have been adding ts to my react project, i'm getting this kind of error: Property 'identifier' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339), the code works as it is but when added ts it gives that error, i can solve it like this:  `currentBroker: "" as any,` but then thats not the right way.
any help/suggestion ?

my code:

```js
const initialSelectionState = {
  currentBroker: "",
};

export function selectionReducer(
  state = initialSelectionState,
  action: selectionReducerAction
) {
  switch (action.type) {
 case ActionType.CHANGE_SITE:
  return {
    ...state,
    currentSite: action.payload,
  };
case ActionType.CHANGE_CAMERA:
  return {
    ...state,
    currentCamera: action.payload,
  };
case ActionType.CHANGE_ANALYSER:
  return {
    ...state,
    currentAnalyser: action.payload,
  };
case ActionType.CHANGE_PLATFORM:
  return {
    ...state,
    currentPlatform: action.payload,
  };
case ActionType.CHANGE_BROKER:
  return {
    ...state,
    currentBroker: action.payload,
  };
case ActionType.CLEAR_ANALYSER_DATA:
  return {
    ...state,
    currentAnalyser: "",
  };
case ActionType.CLEAR_CAMERA_DATA:
  return {
    ...state,
    currentCamera: "",
  };
case ActionType.CLEAR_PLATFORM_DATA:
  return {
    ...state,
    currentPlatform: "",
  };
case ActionType.CLEAR_BROKER_DATA:
  return {
    ...state,
    currentBroker: "",
  };
    case ActionType.UPDATE_BROKER:
      const ucurrentBroker =
        state.currentBroker.identifier == action.payload.identifier
          ? action.payload
          : state.currentBroker;
      return { ...state, currentBroker: ucurrentBroker };
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`currentBroker` is of type string, it's not an object, and  typescript tells you that you cannot access properties because it doesn't have them.

If you are using typescript I suggest you to declare interface of your state first:

```
interface IState {
   currentBroker: string;
}

const initialSelectionState: IState  = {
  currentBroker: "",
};
```

and of you need your broker to have an `identifier` property you can modify the state interface as you need:

```
interface IState {
   currentBroker: {
      identifier: string;
   }
}

const initialSelectionState: IState  = {
  currentBroker: {
    identifier: ""  
  };
};
```

With this you should not have the error again (if I understood correctly)

Comment: is there another way, because doing what you did it gives me another error in some other file: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.' but if i put it as currentBroker: "" as any wont get any error and everything works...

Comment: Can you show me a piece of code where you use this currentBroker from the store?

Comment: Action payload gives this : {identifier: 'b9b6381e-2d42-4953-b747-4b25fd382a04', name: 'Broker 244', host: 'localhost', port: 1783, site_id: '0-0-0-0'}, ?

Comment: And do you need to save the identifier inside currentBroker, right?
Using `as any` you are skipping the type checking that typescript gives you and after the action is called you are going to have inside `currentBroker` a property called `identifier` that holds your value because javascript doesn't complain about that. 
I think the problem is where you use a canvas element in your application but it's not shown in your example. Can you provide a piece of code for that also?

Comment: added code for that

Comment: Usually the error on broken image is caused by the image you are trying to load. Maybe check if the `img` is really that you expect. If it's not I'm sorry but I don't know how to help you

Comment: yes image is correct

Answer (score 1):

You initialise the "currentBroker" as a string.

```
const initialSelectionState = {
  currentBroker: "",
};
```

Then later attempt to access the currentBroker as if it's an object with a property `identifier`

```
state.currentBroker.identifier == action.payload.identifier
```

Casting to any will allow the code to run, and most likely just return `undefined` when trying to get that property.

If all you are trying to do is update a string in a state object, surely no logic is required?

```
const initialSelectionState = {
  currentBroker: "",
};

export function selectionReducer(
  state = initialSelectionState,
  action: selectionReducerAction
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionType.UPDATE_BROKER:
      return { ...state, currentBroker: action.payload};
  }
}
```

Since you mentioned the structure of the payload is as follows;

```
{
  identifier: 'b9b6381e-2d42-4953-b747-4b25fd382a04', 
  name: 'Broker 244', 
  host: 'localhost', 
  port: 1783, 
  site_id: '0-0-0-0'
}
```

Then your `currentBroker` should in some way match the structure of this. Alternatively, if there is 'no current broker initially', you should make it `undefined`. In either case, it definitely shouldn't be an empty string i.e. `""` since that is a totally different data type.

Comment: so what is right way of solving it ? puting currentBroker: "" as any would fix it, any other way ?

Comment: I'll update my answer.

Comment: If the payload is an object, I recommend console.log to see what the actual structure of it is.

In which case, your initial state should either be undefined/null or an empty/uninitialised version of the structure of the payload.

Comment: my action payload is : {identifier: 'b9b6381e-2d42-4953-b747-4b25fd382a04', name: 'Broker 244', host: 'localhost', port: 1783, site_id: '0-0-0-0'}, can help now ?

Comment: So, it's an object and not a string. The currentBroker from your initialSelectionState object should be the same data type or at least be uninitialised. I'll update my answer.

Comment: i added more code which are inside switch, if i solve one i should be able to solve those also...